# How to debug Example_1 of the Open Risk Engine (ORE) library?

Tags: programming, quantlib

Following the manual, I have built an Open Risk Engine library and I would like to learn the library by modifying examples that come together with the library.

**Question:** How to run, for instance, `Example_1` of the ORE library not in excel, by calling `ore.exe`, but the original code in the debug mode at the Visual Studio?

**The problem is:** I am not sure if I can/(how to) change the process used for simulation of the Interest Rate from LGM to for e.g. HW 1F, LMM, Heston, ...  and, **in general,** I would like to know what are the already supported options of the ORE library and how can I modify them.

I have found an `oreapp.cpp` file in `app` of `OREAnalytics` project which, I believe, can be used here. However, I do not know QuantLib and C++, therefore some good basic example of a launchble project with similar outcome as a result of `Example_1.xlam` will be much appreciated.